# Where to get mod_spdy for windows apache server?

Tags: windows

Tried to search everywhere but could not find mod_spdy for windows server. I do not know how to compile.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need to compile it yourself as per the instructions here:

http://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/wiki/GettingStarted

Note that the explicitly supported platforms are Debian/Ubuntu or RHEL/CentOS, as per https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/mod_spdy/.  That doesn't mean you can't get it working under Windows, but you will need to do your own lifting.

There is a mod_spdy discussion list that will probably be able to help you more specifically:

https://groups.google.com/group/mod-spdy-discuss

Comment: It would be appreciated if there was a compiled windows version of this mod_spdy somewhere!